# Download files from ASP forms with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am attempting to download a lot of files from http://www.sl.universalservice.org/funding/opendatasearch/Search1.asp using the Python library mechanize. On the site, the user must fill out 2 ASP forms, and then when the user clicks the second submit button, a file download starts. I was able to get the Python program to go through both forms, but I do not see how to get the file. How can I access the file once I submit the second form?

Comment: How did were you able to fill out the forms? I need to do this as well but am having trouble figuring it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With b as your browser object:

```
b.submit()  # The second of the two forms
c = csv.DictReader(b.response(), dialect='excel-tab')
```

b.response() gives you access to a file-like object, which can be processed by the csv module.